# Don't ask me if I'm sure that I'm finished when there's nothing in the answer box

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, answers

All overflow related websites ask  "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page" etc. etc. any time I try to leave a page after beginning a comment or answer - even if I have deleted ALL text in the input boxes after changing my mind. This is a small thing, but always bothers me. Should it be fixed?

Comment: I curious, and have noticed this previously, too - why is that items that get marked "status-completed" don't also get closed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like SO attaches a listener for "beforeunload" event only after you start writing in a textarea. All that needs to be done here is check for a textarea value in that `onbeforeunload` event handler.

Right now:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return 'You have started writing or editing a post.';
};
```

Could be easily changed to:

```
window.unbeforeunload = function() {
  // check other textareas too
  if ($('#wmd-input').val()) {
    return 'You have started writing or editing a post.';
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. When you return "false". The message that is returned will contain the text "false". I tried this using "return null", which seems to work in FF and Chrome, but not in IE. In IE the text "null" is returned. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a browser thing. For example opera does not do this. Since it doesn't fire `onunload()` properly.

So it would require a check of the data within whatever box was filled (which can by many, since there are comment boxes also). Which might be the reason for this.

Could/should it be fixed? Sure. 
Is there time? No clue.

Comment: Opera is only different because it doesn't fire that event.  It's not really a browser thing - all you'd have to do is add a check for the contents of the textarea. Which I would like.

Comment: onunload() is a function fired by the browser. It's defined within the javascript handling of the browser. (Not StackOverflow). Hence it's a browser thing.

Comment: I actually think it may be a browser thing. Since updating to Safari 4 i seem to be getting a lot more of those messages, so I think browsers may be adding this as a 'feature'.

Comment: That's not a feature, that's a bug!